# Generating huge logs in SQL database

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2, and there is a .net Windows Application which consumes larger XML file from SQL database and generates another large XML and store in another column for each orders. So as we are getting many records due to this xml file transaction, huge logs are getting generating in SQL database and Database is getting slow. To overcome this we are restating the server daily.

So please suggest any way to get rid of larger logs and restating SQL server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean transaction log? What is your recovery model? Are you taking log backups, and with what frequency?

Comment: Recovery model is simple. tempdb.mdf and templog.ldf files are getting generated in C drive.
And when we restart these file free up space. And if we dont restart then tempdb file keeps growing.
Is this the problem causing to slow down the server. Because we have 6 GB RAM.

Comment: Sounds like there's a long running process that keeps the transaction log from being truncated, but you'll most likely get a lot better help if you ask this at https://dba.stackexchange.com and include all the details you have.